# Explain why a given function does not contradict Fubini's Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $\{I_n\}$ is a pairwise disjoint sequence of sub intervals of $[0,1]$ of positive length. For each $n$ let $a_n$ be the reciprocal of the length of $I_n$, and let $g_n$ be the characteristic function of $I_n$ multiplied by $a_n$. Define $f$ by $$f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} [g_n(x)-g_{n+1}(x)]g_n(y)$$ for $0\leq x, y\leq 1$.

I have shown that $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dx dy = 0 \qquad \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dy dx = 1 $$

I now need to explain why this does not contradict Fubini's Theorem. My guess is that $|f(x,y)|$ is not integrable, but I'm not sure how to calculate that integral to prove that.

Comment: Even just integrating $|f|$ over the squares $\{I_n \times I_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ already gives you infinite integral, right? Which is more or less the point of the construction.

Comment: @MeesdeVries that's my thought, but how would I show that? The subtraction in the definition of $f$ is what gives me pause.

Comment: On $I_n \times I_n$, which has area $1/a_n^2$, the only functions used in your summation which are non-zero are $g_n(x)$ and $g_n(y)$. Hence you can focus on the $n$th term in the sum (otherwise $g_n(y)$ ensures the term is zero) and therefore only on $g_n(x)g_n(y) = a_n^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}|f(x,y)|\operatorname{d}x\operatorname{d}y\ge\int_{\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}I_n\times I_n}|f(x,y)|\operatorname{d}x\operatorname{d}y\\ =\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\int_{I_n\times I_n}|f(x,y)|\operatorname{d}x\operatorname{d}y = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\int_{I_n\times I_n}\frac{1}{|I_n|^2}\operatorname{d}x\operatorname{d}y = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} 1 = +\infty$$